# hive is not allowed to impersonate hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, beeline

I have a hadoop cluster configured with hadoop 2.7.2 and hive 2.1.0.

I am using beeline to connect to hive with the following command:

```
beeline
beeline> !connect jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000
Enter username for jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000:
```

At first, type any user name can successfully connect to hive. However, after configuring the folloing setting, error appears.

```
//within hive-site.xml and hiveserver2-site.xml
<property>
<name>hive.server2.enable.doAs</name>
<value>true</value>
<description>
  Setting this property to true will have HiveServer2 execute
  Hive operations as the user making the calls to it.
</description>
</property>

//within core-site.xml
<property>
<name>hadoop.proxyuser.hive.hosts</name>
<value>*</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hive.groups</name>
  <value>*</value>
</property>
```

I have restarted hadoop cluster, but the following message still appears:

```
Error: Failed to open new session: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.AuthorizationException): User: hive is not allowed to impersonate hive (state=,code=0)
```

The debug output for hiveserver2 is as following:

```
    16/11/15 11:28:46 [IPC Client (241742811) connection to /10.104.90.40:8020 from hive]: DEBUG ipc.Client: IPC Client (241742811) connection to /10.104.90.40:8020 from hive: starting, having connections 1
16/11/15 11:28:46 [IPC Client (241742811) connection to /10.104.90.40:8020 from hive]: DEBUG ipc.Client: IPC Client (241742811) connection to /10.104.90.40:8020 from hive got value #-3
16/11/15 11:28:46 [IPC Client (241742811) connection to /10.104.90.40:8020 from hive]: DEBUG ipc.Client: closing ipc connection to /10.104.90.40:8020: User: hive is not allowed to impersonate hive
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.AuthorizationException): User: hive is not allowed to impersonate hive
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1475)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1412)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy27.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:771)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy28.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:2108)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1305)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1301)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1301)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1424)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createRootHDFSDir(SessionState.java:674)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createSessionDirs(SessionState.java:622)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:550)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:513)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.open(HiveSessionImpl.java:165)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy.invoke(HiveSessionProxy.java:78)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy.access$000(HiveSessionProxy.java:36)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy$1.run(HiveSessionProxy.java:63)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy.invoke(HiveSessionProxy.java:59)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy45.open(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.SessionManager.createSession(SessionManager.java:327)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.SessionManager.openSession(SessionManager.java:279)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService.openSessionWithImpersonation(CLIService.java:189)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService.getSessionHandle(ThriftCLIService.java:414)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService.OpenSession(ThriftCLIService.java:310)
        at org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$OpenSession.getResult(TCLIService.java:1377)
        at org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$OpenSession.getResult(TCLIService.java:1362)
        at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
        at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
        at org.apache.hive.service.auth.TSetIpAddressProcessor.process(TSetIpAddressProcessor.java:56)
        at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:286)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/11/15 11:28:46 [IPC Client (241742811) connection to /10.104.90.40:8020 from hive]: DEBUG ipc.Client: IPC Client (241742811) connection to /10.104.90.40:8020 from hive: closed
16/11/15 11:28:46 [IPC Client (241742811) connection to /10.104.90.40:8020 from hive]: DEBUG ipc.Client: IPC Client (241742811) connection to /10.104.90.40:8020 from hive: stopped, remaining connections 0
16/11/15 11:28:46 [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-38]: WARN service.CompositeService: Failed to open session
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.AuthorizationException): User: hive is not allowed to impersonate hive
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy.invoke(HiveSessionProxy.java:89)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy.access$000(HiveSessionProxy.java:36)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy$1.run(HiveSessionProxy.java:63)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy.invoke(HiveSessionProxy.java:59)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy45.open(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.SessionManager.createSession(SessionManager.java:327)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.SessionManager.openSession(SessionManager.java:279)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService.openSessionWithImpersonation(CLIService.java:189)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService.getSessionHandle(ThriftCLIService.java:414)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService.OpenSession(ThriftCLIService.java:310)
        at org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$OpenSession.getResult(TCLIService.java:1377)
        at org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$OpenSession.getResult(TCLIService.java:1362)
        at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
        at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
        at org.apache.hive.service.auth.TSetIpAddressProcessor.process(TSetIpAddressProcessor.java:56)
        at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:286)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.AuthorizationException): User: hive is not allowed to impersonate hive
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:578)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:513)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.open(HiveSessionImpl.java:165)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy.invoke(HiveSessionProxy.java:78)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.AuthorizationException): User: hive is not allowed to impersonate hive
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1475)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1412)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy27.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:771)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy28.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:2108)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1305)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1301)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1301)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1424)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createRootHDFSDir(SessionState.java:674)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createSessionDirs(SessionState.java:622)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:550)
        ... 28 more
16/11/15 11:28:46 [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-38]: DEBUG security.UserGroupInformation: PrivilegedAction as:hive (auth:PROXY) via hive (auth:SIMPLE) from:org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy.invoke(HiveSessionProxy.java:59)
16/11/15 11:28:46 [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-38]: INFO session.SessionState: Updating thread name to 74dcfeae-04c1-494d-b491-df53f0d20039 HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-38
16/11/15 11:28:46 [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-38]: INFO session.SessionState: Resetting thread name to  HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-38
16/11/15 11:28:46 [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-38]: DEBUG session.SessionState: Removing resource dir /tmp/hive_resources
16/11/15 11:28:46 [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-38]: INFO hive.metastore: Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://10.104.90.40:9083
16/11/15 11:28:46 [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-38]: INFO hive.metastore: Opened a connection to metastore, current connections: 3
16/11/15 11:28:46 [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-38]: INFO hive.metastore: Connected to metastore.
16/11/15 11:28:46 [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-38]: DEBUG metadata.Hive: Closing current thread's connection to Hive Metastore.
16/11/15 11:28:46 [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-38]: INFO hive.metastore: Closed a connection to metastore, current connections: 2
16/11/15 11:28:46 [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-38]: DEBUG ipc.Client: stopping client from cache: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client@78fd9232
16/11/15 11:28:47 [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-38]: WARN thrift.ThriftCLIService: Error opening session: 
org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Failed to open new session: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.AuthorizationException): User: hive is not allowed to impersonate hive
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.SessionManager.createSession(SessionManager.java:336)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.SessionManager.openSession(SessionManager.java:279)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService.openSessionWithImpersonation(CLIService.java:189)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService.getSessionHandle(ThriftCLIService.java:414)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService.OpenSession(ThriftCLIService.java:310)
        at org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$OpenSession.getResult(TCLIService.java:1377)
        at org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$OpenSession.getResult(TCLIService.java:1362)
        at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
        at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
        at org.apache.hive.service.auth.TSetIpAddressProcessor.process(TSetIpAddressProcessor.java:56)
        at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:286)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.AuthorizationException): User: hive is not allowed to impersonate hive
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy.invoke(HiveSessionProxy.java:89)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy.access$000(HiveSessionProxy.java:36)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy$1.run(HiveSessionProxy.java:63)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy.invoke(HiveSessionProxy.java:59)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy45.open(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.SessionManager.createSession(SessionManager.java:327)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.AuthorizationException): User: hive is not allowed to impersonate hive
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:578)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:513)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.open(HiveSessionImpl.java:165)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy.invoke(HiveSessionProxy.java:78)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.AuthorizationException): User: hive is not allowed to impersonate hive
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1475)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1412)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy27.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:771)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy28.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:2108)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1305)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1301)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1301)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1424)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createRootHDFSDir(SessionState.java:674)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createSessionDirs(SessionState.java:622)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:550)
        ... 28 more
```

I searched online and found most solution related to this error is actualLy the setting I configured which causes the problem.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Update:

After some try, I found out that this error relate to which user being used to start hive service.

Before I have user **hive** to start hive metastore and hiveserver2 which leads to the error message.

But using user **hadoop** which is the user who started hadoop namenode  to start hiveserver2 get rid of the error message.

I didn't figure out the reason why using different user is a temporary workaround.

Comment: Why do you want to start the metastore with a specific user (why not just hadoop?). -- Just a guess, but perhaps the user that starts the metastore defines where configs/logs are placed. And for some users these locations may not exist or may not be accesible enough.

Comment: At first, it's because most of those tutorial online use hive as the user. But later on, I thought may be using hive for all the hive services isn't unnecessary sice hive user only have the privilege on hive folder, it can't screw up the hadoop or spark folder.

Comment: Perhaps I am drawing the wrong conclusion from your comment, but if you are worried about accessing the wrong folders, I would recommend you to only use the 'standard' user accounts for the initial setup, and then do the work with custom user accounts. (Like Wang, and adminWang).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. You are right about what I mean in the last comment.  **hive**  is like the 'standard' user accounts who did the initial setup for hive service and  **hadoop** in this case would be the custom user as in your suggestion. The strange thing is using 'standard' user who did the initial set up to start hiveserver2 actually causes the error.

Comment: If I recall correctly hadoop is also a system user in a way. Please make sure to actually create a new user before doing any real work.

Answer (score 22):

Stumbled across this thread while facing the same issue. I tried changing impersonation property in hive-site.xml to get it working. Hope this helps someone else.

```
  <property>
  <name>hive.server2.enable.doAs</name>
  <value>false</value> 
  </property>
```

Comment: Worked. I set everything as shown, however I neglected a detail: I was running the app from Intellij, which wasn't run using the specified user. I disabled the doAs property as shown and then could run my "Hive using JDBC driver" app.

Comment: thanks, it works! you save my live! this setting is exactly what missing from other suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue too. This is what I did to make it work.
In the hive-site.xml, you have this property:

```
    <property>
      <name>hive.conf.restricted.list</name>
      <value>hive.security.authenticator.manager,hive.security.authorization.manager,**hive.users.in.admin.role**</value>
    </property>
```

I just removed the part highlighted above in Bold :     **hive.users.in.admin.role.**

It started working for me.